# Script to recursively remove specific file from child paths?

Tags: file, powershell, recursion, vbscript

I've tried searching for this answer for awhile now, but can't seem to find what I'm after. Perhaps I'm wording it strangely.

I need a script that will recursively delete a specific file from each child directory in a network share.

For example:

```
\\\share\\*\a\b\file.settings
```

The * represents *n* number of child directories. The rest of the path will always be the same. It seems like I might be able to do this with a combination of `Get-childitem` and `remove-item` in Powershell, but I'm having trouble working out the exact command I need.

Any help would be immensely appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking out my comment code into long form:

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem "\\server\share\" -Directory

ForEach ($folder in $folders) {
    $file = Join-Path $folder.FullName "\a\b\file.settings"
    if (Test-Path $file) { Remove-Item $file } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! While I'm no longer working on this particular issue, this appears to be right way to go about it in PowerShell.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should work:

```psh
Get-ChildItem '\\server\share' -Recurse | ? {
  $_.FullName -like '*\a\b\file.settings'
} | Remove-Item
```

If you're just interested in files `.\a\b\file.settings` in the immediate child folders of `\\server\share` you could simplify the code to something like this:

```psh
Get-ChildItem '\\server\share\*\a\b\file.settings' | Remove-Item
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I was way off with what I was trying. I still can't get this to run right for some reason though; it just hangs when I run it. In the end, I put together something in VBScript which appears to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

While I wasn't able to get this to work with Powershell, the below VBS I put together does seem to work well:

```
Set FSfolder = FSO.GetFolder(\\server\share)

For Each subfolder In FSfolder.SubFolders

    UserProfile=subfolder.Name
    SettingFile="\\server\share\" & UserProfile & "\a\b\file.settings"
    If FSO.FileExists(SettingFile) Then
        FSO.DeleteFile(SettingFile)
    End If

Next
```

Comment: The PowerShell code from Ansgar tries to list every single file in the entire share including all subfolders, no wonder it seems to hang. This code does enormously less work, testing one file per folder. Like   `gci '\\server\share\' -Directory | % { Join-Path $_.FullName "\a\b\file.settings" | Remove-Item -ErrorAction Ignore }`